# Next JS/ Sass loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, visual-studio-code, sass

I was developing a portfolio for a friends earlier today and all was fine. All of a sudden i get a message saying i don't have sass installed, even though I installed in and had been running on port 3000 the better half of the day already.
the error that puts me into a literal loop installing and uninstlling sass to run
next dev
or
yarn dev
I have looked several places for documentation and cant quite seem to figure out what went wrong and how to fix it.
Please help and let me know if more info is needed! (This is from the terminal)
"
PS C:\Users\coach\Desktop\portfolio> npm i sass

added 1 package, removed 1 package, changed 12 packages, and audited 110 packages in 7s

20 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\coach\Desktop\portfolio> next dev
warn  - Port 3000 is in use, trying 3001 instead.
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3001, url: http://localhost:3001
error - ./src/styles/home.scss
To use Next.js' built-in Sass support, you first need to install `sass`.
Run `npm i sass` or `yarn add sass` inside your workspace.

Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/install-sass

"

I have tried installing and uninstalling sass both through npm and yarn, neither of which have worked.

UPDATED: This is the error I recieve on my local host
"
./src/styles/home.scss
To use Next.js' built-in Sass support, you first need to install `sass`.
Run `npm i sass` or `yarn add sass` inside your workspace.

Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/install-sass
"

sass has been installed and shows in my package.JSON file.
I am wondering how to fix this, it says it is only a problem in the ./src/styles/home.scss, I'm just not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12263. You will need to also install node-sass to work with sass on nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from Node `v16` to `v18` and it worked.